# Объединение одинаковых строк и их значений из text файла

Tags: c#, массивы, строки

Есть такой текст:
**red 1
orange 3
orange 1
blue 4
white 2
red 4**
Нужно чтобы после всех манипуляций получилось
**red 5
orange 4
blue 4
white 2**
Через Split пробовал разделять "слова" и "значения" и сравнивать между собой, но не получилось. Есть код на поиск максимального и значений и текстового файла. И вот призадумался как объединить повторяющиеся слова и просуммировать значения
Сам код на поиск макс элемента:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            string[] openText = File.ReadAllLines("original.txt");
            int max = 0;
            string line;
            for (int i = 0; i < openText.Length; i++)
            {
                line = openText[i];
               
                if (GetCount(openText[max]) < GetCount(openText[i]))
                {
                    max = i;
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(GetWord(openText[max]));
           


        }
        static string GetWord(string line)
        {
            string[] splited = line.Split(' ');
            string word = splited[0];
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(splited[1]);
            return word;
        }
        static int GetCount(string line)
        {
            string[] splited= line.Split(' ');
            string word = splited[0];
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(splited[1]);
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: Оставлю это, пожалуй, здесь: `var result = string.Join(' ', text.Split().Chunk(2).GroupBy(x => x[0]).Select(x => $"{x.Key} {x.Sum(s => int.Parse(s[1]))}"));`

Comment: Ругается на Chunk(2)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, вы забыли исключить повторяющиеся элементы

Comment: @Hannibal [.Chunk()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-6.0) - это метод из LINQ, который появился в .NET6. Если вы не используете последнюю версию языка (что весма печально), то ищите альтернативы, раз хотите запустить мой код, например [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362642/6808809). Цель - разбить массив значений на куски по 2 объекта в каждом. А так, можно пойти другим путем, например разбивать строку по 2-му пробелу и так далее.

Comment: @Yotic С чего это вдруг? `GroupBy` тут думаете просто так?

Comment: А, только сейчас узнал, что GroupBy убирает лишнее, а ведь я его когда-то использовал для показа таблицы лучших игроков, Что бы было, если бы какой-нибудь игрок написал об том, что его нет в таблице... Долго наверное я бы думал над ошибкой

Comment: Я думаю тут нужен Regex по хорошему и уже с помощью Regex разбивать массив на слова (Я не знаю синтаксис Regex)

Comment: @Yotic `GroupBy` - не убирает лишнее, он группирует в нечто, похожее на словарь, где ключом будет то, по чему группируем, а значением - массив из того, что подходит под этот ключ. Ну и при помощи этой штуки и получается, что ключом будет слово, а из полученного массива высчитываем сумму.

Comment: @Hannibal Вот вам [2 варианта](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hGYqCQ): с Chunk и без. Только учтите, я не говорю, что это решение вашей задачи, я лишь показываю, как можно. Если вам надо лишь получить результат, который просите, то это решение подойдет, а если это учебное задание, то лучше пробуйте циклами, а мой пример просто воспринимайте как "возможность".

Answer (score 0):

Ответ от EvgeniyZ:

```
var result = string.Join(' ', text.Split().Select((x, i) => (Index: i, Item: x)).GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2).Select(x=>x.Select(v => v.Item)).GroupBy(x => x.First()).Select(x => $"{x.Key} {x.Sum(s => int.Parse(s.Last()))}"));
```

Мой развёрнутый ответ:

```
string[] input = "red 1 orange 3 orange 1 blue 4 white 2 red 4".Split(' ');
List<(string, int)> rawResult = new List<(string, int)>();
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 1)
    rawResult.Add((input[i], int.Parse(input[++i])));
string result = string.Join(" ", rawResult.Select(z => (z.Item1, rawResult.FindAll(x => x.Item1 == z.Item1).Select(x => x.Item2).Sum())).Distinct().Select(z => string.Join(" ", z.Item1, z.Item2.ToString())));
```

Тут старый код: https://pastebin.com/hvHcx4hN

Comment: `**red 1** orange 3 orange 1 blue 4 white 2 **red 4**` (2 red, у одного 1, у другого 4. 4+1 = 5). Аналогично и с orange. Так что, ваш код не делает то, что требуется. Смотрю кстати появились нормальные наименования, что радует)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Ох как же нужен Chunk, а так придётся писать увесистый код

Comment: Я последним комментарием дал ссылку, там два варианта "однострочника", с `Chunk` и без. Но опять же, если у автора это учебное задание (а это так и есть), то лучше без всяких сокращений, с циклами, увесистый код, да еще и описание того, что там происходит. Так что, если есть желание - делайте, а пока, в таком виде, ответ не в тему.

Comment: Сделал через перебор массивов, создал пустые массивы и в них через сравнение начал добавлять строки и значения. Но код получился очень увесистый и не красивый, если можно так сказать. А по поводу Chunk вот что он пишет 
Ошибка CS1061 "string[]" не содержит определения "Chunk", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Chunk", принимающий тип "string[]" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку). 
using System.Linq; подключил

Comment: @Hannibal, что за платформу ты используешь? Net 6.0?

Comment: @Hannibal Я вам под вопросом все про `Chunk` ведь сказал, это нововведение .NET6, если у вас проект не этой версии, забудьте про него, делая вручную то, что он делает за вас. Как - я показал последним комментарием, другие альтернативы я указал ссылкой на en SO. Мало чтоль этого не пойму..?

Comment: Консольное приложение, платформа 4.72.  А создать новый проект там можно поставить только 4.8. Само приложение у меня свежее, совсем не давно было установлено

Comment: @Hannibal .NET Framework давно уже устарел, не развивается, заброшен. Хотите всех новшеств, ставьте последнюю Visual Studio и делайте проект под .NET6 (скоро будет еще и .NET7).

Comment: хмм, напоминает версии WinForms, Если у вас VS 2022, то у создайте новый проект выберите 6.0

Comment: У меня Visual Studio 2022 версия 17.1.2 , но какой я не пробовал создавать проект, везде стоит .Net FrameWork 4.8. Можете его можно как то вручную установить?

Comment: Cоздание проекта -> ConsoleApp -> Net 6.0
Так?

Comment: Да, у меня там стоит 4.8. Попробовал только что вручную установить net FrameWork 6.0. Установил, но ничего не поменялось. В Visual Studio Installer не могу найти пакет для установки. В данный момент у меня стоит Visual studio Community 2022

Comment: @Hannibal Вот же [он](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjmri.png). И да, внимание все [на тип проекта](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydk0i.png), там несколько консолей, WPF, WinForms и прочее!

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/V1cNrMF
Вот так у меня выглядит создание проекта (скрин 2) и дополнительные библиотеки для Visual Studio

Comment: Вы выбираете не то консольное приложение

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6GZBcES вот такое выбираю

Comment: @Hannibal Еще раз почитайте мой коммент выше, там 2 ссылки, клик на 2-ю, увидите, что консольных проектов минимум 2, вы выбираете `(.NET Framework)`, когда должны выбирать без этой приписки

Comment: https://youtu.be/vMLFFw1Tk60

Comment: Я увидел. Спасибо большое! Теперь  я могу не бить камень об камень, чтобы сделать огонь, а сразу возьму огнемет